# go to an url without opening it in browser, for digital leds control with android app

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to control my Esp8266 (with some awesome leds on it) with an android app (making it in android studio). I have to go to a URL to set them to a different function.

I got it to work already by using an Intent, shown below. If I press the button now and go to the URL in browser, this works! But it would be way nicer if I press the button I wouldn't go to the browser and it would still execute the URL.

I already tried a lot of things but it just doesn't want to work. if anyone could help me that would be awesome!

```
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://192.168.0.157/ledsoff?fade=500"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to open browser? What if you just send GET request?

```
import java.net.URL;
btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new URL("http://192.168.0.157/ledsoff?fade=500").openStream();
        }
    });
```

Comment: i have tried this and added a toast with it and it says that he executes the url. the only problem is that my leds don't change :/ they should go out with this button, but they don't. so i am doing something wrong but i don't know what :/

Answer (score 0):

i have an other idea with 2 Buttons. LedOn and LedOff.
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-web-server-arduino-ide/
My Code based on his ESP32 Code. You can also use it on Esp8266.

Create a WebView on activity_main.xml and set visible to gone. So noboby kann see it.

In MainActivity :

```
Button buttonLedOn;
Button buttonLedOff;
WebView web1 ;
```

In OnCreate():

```
buttonLedOn = findViewById(R.id.b_LedOn);
buttonLedOn = findViewById(R.id.b_LedOff);
web1 = findViewById(R.id.webViewOnLayout);

buttonLedOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            web.loadUrl(http://IP_ADDRESS/27/on);

        }
    });
buttonLedOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            web.loadUrl(http://IP_ADDRESS/27/off);

        }
    });
```